# Porque me imprime los numero en lugar de la suma

Tags: python

Ayuda estoy empezando con python intento hacer una calculadora pero al momento de dar el resultado me imprime los dos numero seguidos en lugar del resultado

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from _ast import If
print("Bienvenido a la calculadora ");
print("1= suma")
print("2= resta")
print("3 = Multiplicacion")
print("4 = Division")
opcion = int(input("Seleccione una opcion"))

a = input("Ingrese un número:")
b = input("Ingrese un número")
print("El resultado es " + str(a+b))
```

Comment: Hola, por lo que me acuerdo de Python el input siempre es String, entonces estas sumando 2 strings. seria bueno convertirlos a numeros los variables a y b antes de sumarlos ;D

Answer (score 2):

seria de la siguiente manera.
Te explico el porque, al momento de ingresar el `input` de `Ingrese un numero` el valor es un String, por lo tanto se debera usar `int()` para convertir el String a entero antes de realizar una suma, restar, multiplicacion o division.

```
from _ast import If
print("Bienvenido a la calculadora ");
print("1= suma")
print("2= resta")
print("3 = Multiplicacion")
print("4 = Division")
opcion = int(input("Seleccione una opcion"))

a = input("Ingrese un número:")
b = input("Ingrese un número")
if opcion==1:
    print("El resultado es " + str(int(a)+int(b)))
elif opcion==2:
    print("El resultado es " + str(int(a)-int(b)))
elif opcion==3:
    print("El resultado es " + str(int(a)*int(b)))
elif opcion==4:
    print("El resultado es " + str(int(a)/int(b)))
```